# SQL statement to show the total cost of all orders per Customer

Tags: sql, grouping

I am new to SQL and am having trouble with this query, I have a table called Orders, with columns CustomerName, OrderDate, and Amount.

I need to write an SQL statement to show the total cost of all orders per customer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CustomerName, SUM(Amount)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select customername,sum(amount) from orders group by customername
```